Assign mail body from Razor file
I want to assign mail body from razor file Instead of using direct HTML string
I tried the following but no luck:
string _template = File.ReadAllText("Components/Emails/template.razor");
mail.Body = _template;

Any help please?
Thanks in advance

Do you mean you want to use a component to output html that is used as the body of the email?  Is so see - https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-rendering-blazor-components-to-a-string/
